# How to update from Craft version 2 to 4?

Tags: database, updates, updating, content

I'm working with a Craft site that's running on version 2.6 and I need to get it updated to the latest version. My first approach was to just start a fresh site and then import the existing database, which caused a bunch of errors. Then I tried updating the current site manually but just getting it to run on my local environment proved to be difficult. So, I'm a bit stumped on how to move forward. One option I guess is to input all the entries/fields/sections manually into a fresh site but there is a lot of content so that seems extremely time-consuming.

If anyone has experience updating a site from that many versions back, do you have any advice for making this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can upgrade the Craft 2.6 site to Craft 4, you'll need to upgrade the site to the latest Craft 2 release (2.9.2) first.

The next step is getting that Craft 2 install upgraded to the latest Craft 3 release. This part will be the most work by far; make sure to follow [the official guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html) carefully.

Once you've successfully migrated the Craft 2 database to run with the latest 3.x release, have installed the latest Craft 4 compatible version of all plugins and made sure that your [Twig templates are compatible with Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/preparing-for-craft-4#prepare-your-templates-for-twig-3), actually getting the site [upgraded to Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/upgrade.html) should be relatively easy. If you run into any issues with Composer, see [this issue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39393/upgrade-to-craft-4).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Finally, managed to get the site upgraded to Craft 4.